# How to get the Facebook followers or subscribers count for Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API version 2.0. to get the Facebook followers and subscribers count for some users.

I used util April 30th 2015 to get the followers/subscribers count by using the following URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER-ID/subscribers?access_token=TOKEN-NR
```

But now I get this error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#12) subscribers field is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 12
   }
}
```

Comment: This is removed with no replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer get the number of subscribers through the facebook API.